# PHP website - mysql DB - function array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

**I have the button which adds fields in my DB:**
I want to add a button on my mysql php webpage to add some fields into the database.

```
    <div class ="row">
                    <!-- blacklist button -->

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <h4 class="page-title"><font color="#e34749">Adaugare Blacklist</font></h4>
                       <div class="card-box">


                       <?php
$q = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$update_id = $q;
if (isset($_POST["adauga_user_blacklist"])) {dbuserInsertblacklist('blacklist', $form_user_blacklist); }
?>
                        <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Nume client</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <input type="text" name="numeb" class="form-control" placeholder="Nume client pentru banat">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Telefon</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <input type="text" name="telefonb" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefon client pentru banat">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Motiv</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <input type="text" name="motivb" class="form-control" placeholder="Motivul banarii ">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                          <div align="center"><button type="submit" name="adauga_user_blacklist" class="btn btn-danger btn-trans waves-effect w-md waves-info  btn-lg m-b-5"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <span>Adauga</span> </button></div>     
                        </form>
                       </div>
                    </div>


                    </div>
```

**In functions I have:**

```
// Form user blacklist - banat

$nume_blacklist = $_POST['numeb'];
$telefon_blacklist = $_POST['telefonb'];
$motiv_blacklist = $_POST['motivb'];

$form_user_blacklist = array(
    'nume_blacklist' =>  $numeb,    
    'telefon_blacklist' =>  $telefonb,  
    'motiv_blacklist' =>  $motivb
);


function dbuserInsertblacklist($table_name, $form_user_blacklist) {
    // retrieve the keys of the array (column titles)
    $fields = array_keys($form_user_blacklist);
    $error = "";
if (empty($_POST['numeb']) OR empty($_POST['telefonb']) OR empty($_POST['motivb'])) { echo "<div align='center'> <h4><font color='#f0ad4b'>* Va rugam sa completati toate campurile!</font></h4></div>"; $error=1; }    

if ($error !=1) {
    // build the query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name."
    (`".implode('`,`', $fields)."`)
    VALUES('".implode("','", $form_user_blacklist)."')";

    //Display ID

    echo "<div align='center'> <h4><font color='#10c469'>* A fost adaugat angajatul in baza de date.</font></h4></div>";
}   
    // run and return the query result resource
    return mysql_query($sql);
}
// end utilizatori

// Delete dbRowDelete('my_table', "WHERE id = '$id'");
// End function blacklist gsm
```

**DB is created - but it does not add the values - it adds blank...**
**Any help appreciated.**

Comment: Please, please, please, read about sql injection and how to guard against it. If you properly sanitize your code we might take a look at it. As it stands, it's a gaping security hole.

Comment: "Please debug my code for me" is not what SE is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself meanwhile - the POST function database name had to be the same as the one in the array.
[ FIXED ]

@ Daan Meijer - about SQL - code is not public - I have not yet converted all / its only for a local project at the moment